# upload product image from external url using object manager

Tags: magento-2.1

**i want to upload image from url to magento media path using object manager
i have created a code for it 
the url image is saved to my media folder but not assigning to product
it returns that image doesn't exist but the file was uploaded to my temp_upload folder**

Any suggestion would be helpful

```
public function addImageFromUrl($urlToImage)
    {
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
    $mySaveDir  =  $directory->getRoot()."/pub/media/temp_upload/";
    $filename = basename($urlToImage);
    $completeSaveLoc = $mySaveDir.$filename;
     if(!file_exists($completeSaveLoc)){
         try {
             file_put_contents($completeSaveLoc,file_get_contents($urlToImage));
             return $completeSaveLoc;
            }
         catch (Exception $e){
              echo $e->getMessage();
                }
     }
}
$imageUrlPath = "https://www.festisite.com/static/partylogo/img/logos/google.png";
if(!empty($imageUrlPath))
    {
    $returnUploadedImagePath = $this->addImageFromUrl($imageUrlPath);
    $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($returnUploadedImagePath, array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false);               
    }
```

Comment: have you fine solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to move your file from

> /pub/media/temp_upload/

directory to

> pub/media/catalog/product

using core PHP function `move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )`

Either you can use Magento's

`$this->getImageUploader()->moveFileFromTmp($image);`

And after that return Media path.